# gitlab yaml anchors and extends fails

Tags: docker, gitlab

Given this `.gitlab-ci.yaml`, why doesn't `extends:` or YAML anchors work? I can't figure it out.

[The docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/yaml_optimization.html#yaml-anchors-for-scripts) suggest I'm doing this the right way.

I'm expecting to see `foo.txt` on the second `ls -al`.

I'm aware that a new container is spun up per job. The bigger requirement is to avoid copy and paste lots of identical lines for each job and just define them as one job then include the same thing across multiple jobs and stages.

In other words, I want to `touch foo.txt` across many jobs and many stages but only define `- touch foo.txt` once.

```
image: alpine:3.18.0
stages:
  - ...
  - build
  - ...

.prep: &prep
  script:
    - touch foo.txt
    - ls -al
    - echo "PREP PREP PREP"

build-job:
  stage: build
  image: docker:24.0.0
  before_script: *prep
  script:
    - ls -al
    - echo "build job"
```

Linter error: `This GitLab CI configuration is invalid: jobs:build-job:before_script config should be a string or a nested array of strings up to 10 levels deep`

---

```
.prep: &prep
  script:
    - touch foo.txt
    - ls -al

build-job:
  stage: build
  image: docker:24.0.0
  before_script:
    - *prep
  script:
    - ls -al
    - echo "build job"
```

Linter error: `jobs:build-job:before_script config should be a string or a nested array of strings up to 10 levels deep`

---

```
.prep:
  script:
    - touch foo.txt

build-job:
  stage: build
  extends: .prep
  script:
    - ls -al
```

No linter errors this time and job succeeds but I don't see `foo.txt`:

```
$ ls -al
total 36
drwxrwxrwx    3 root     root          4096 May 17 05:30 .
drwxrwxrwx    4 root     root          4096 May 15 06:40 ..
drwxrwxrwx    6 root     root          4096 May 17 05:30 .git
-rw-rw-rw-    1 root     root         14824 May 17 05:30 .gitlab-ci.yml
-rw-rw-rw-    1 root     root          6205 May 15 06:40 README.md
```

---

## !reference

[!reference tags](https://docs.gitlab.com/15.11/ee/ci/yaml/yaml_optimization.html#reference-tags) don't work either

```
.prep:
  script:
    - touch foo.txt

build-job:
  stage: build
  extends: .prep
  script:
    - !reference [.prep]
    - ls -al
```

---

## References

Answer (score 0):

## Answer `default`:

If you, like me, just want [a default script](https://docs.gitlab.com/15.11/ee/ci/yaml/script.html#set-a-default-before_script-or-after_script-for-all-jobs) to execute for everything, use:

```
default:
  before_script:
    - touch foo.txt
```

Then:

```
build-job:
  stage: build
  script:
    - ls -al       # this shows that foo.txt exists
```